# need to update the logic and deploy web app bot | deployment error

Tags: azure-web-app-service, botframework, azure-cli, azure-bot-service, kudu

I had created a web app bot on Azure earlier and it was working well. After updating logic when I tried to deploy from local machine using Azure CLI, it results into zip deployment error.

detailed error on latest deployment URL : ...api/deployments/latest/log

message     "An error has occurred."
ExceptionMessage    "No log found for 'latest'."
ExceptionType   "System.IO.FileNotFoundException"

is it because the Web app bot is deprecated? if not please help.

Comment: Could you please re-try with the latest version of CLI  and deploy and let us know if you see the same issue.

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT I got the Same error when I deployed it with the latest version of Azure CLI (2.32.0)

Answer (score 0):

Try with --timeout

Default timeout is set at az webapp deployment source Config-ZIP

If deployment takes longer, it usually throw the error and it will exit.

Run the command with a long timeout as above --timeout